# Spring Security - DB Authorization with a default authority?

Tags: authorization, spring-security

In Spring security 3 - can I declaratively define a default authority to be assigned to all authenticated users that are authenticated using the jdbc authentication provider? Currently my webapp does not have the concept of roles (nor will it - you either are a user allowed to access your account or you are not) and I don't want to implement an authority table in my database as it would be redundant. Currently with the below declaration i get the following error message.

> message [Table 'authorities' doesn't
>   exist];

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                               users-by-username-query="select account_uid,hashedpassword,true from account where account_uid=?" />

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

If this cannot be done declaratively - what would be the best approach be?

Thanks In Advance,

Ian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<jdbc-user-service>` element is handled by the `JdbcUserServiceBeanDefinitionParser` class, which in turn instantiates and configures a `JdbcUserDetailsManager` bean. This bean contains the relevant SQL to managed users, groups and authorities.

If you look at the source code for `JdbcUserDetailsManager`, you'll see that it's pretty limited in its flexibility.  If you don't want a user authorities table, it requires you to have a group authorities table instead. One or the other.

If you want something simpler, it looks like you'll have to write your own custom implementation of `UserDetailsService`. If you do that and declare it as a normal Spring bean in the context, you can hook it up to Spring Security using:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserService">
        <password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Perhaps copying the source for `JdbcUserDetailsManager` and removing the authority/group stuff would be the easiest approach.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a simple way:

authorities-by-username-query="select account_uid, 'default' from account where account_uid=?"

This query reuses your account table and gives each user a default authority.